# Custom Styling radio-buttons and check-boxes

Tags: checkboxes, radio-buttons, style

I am trying to customize my checkbox and radio buttons.**[This](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96798895/custom.html)** is what I have come up so far:

[image]

I want to know if this is clickable enough? Is there any rulebook to consider while designing user controls?

Comment: @nashmaniac, isn't this question some how related to UX?

Comment: @AnujKaithwas You're really just asking for a UX review of your form styling, which is too localised and unlikely to be useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

From a UX standpoint, you may want to use different icons inside the radio buttons than the same check mark used in the checkbox. The same check mark for both check boxes and radio buttons may be confusing for the user, especially if the controls are close in proximity to each other.

Answer (score 0):

From a design standpoint, the dropshadow on the text box makes it look more clickable than the button. I am assuming the dropshadow box is for text entry.

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox and radio buttons aren't obvious as being clickable. I think users are going to overlook these designs because they look like icons.